# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Таблица 1:

```
  CREATE TABLE `airline`.`appointment` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Таблица 2:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `airline`.`gender` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
   ENGINE = InnoDB
   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Таблица 3:

```
        CREATE TABLE `airline`.`employee` (
       `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `genderFK` INT NOT NULL,
       `firstName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
       `lastName` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
       `appointmentFK` INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE `id_idx` (`genderFK` ASC),
        UNIQUE `id_idx1` (`appointmentFK` ASC),
        CONSTRAINT `id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`genderFK`)
        REFERENCES `airline`.`gender` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT `id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`appointmentFK`)
        REFERENCES `airline`.`appointment` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Не проходит скрипт для создания Таблицы 3.

**Ошибка**: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Что не так делаю?

Comment: А почему у вас констраинты называются id, так же как и поле id ? Имена констраинтов, раз вы их решили написать, должны быть уникальны

Comment: И кстати, зачем уникальные ключи по полям genderFK и appointmentFK у вас же во всей таблице сможет быть только по одному сотруднику одного пола и при этом они будут обязаны работать в разных авиакомпаниях

Comment: @Mike, 1 убрал constraint - ошибка ушла. Можете пояснить почему? 2 изменить связь на 1 ко мн?

Comment: Можно было оставить слово constaraint но написать вместо id _уникальное_ имя, вы же тем же UNIQUE даете уникальные имена, например `id_idx`, внешний ключ как и индексы это отдельный объект базы данных и у него должно быть собственное имя, вот оно и пишется после слова constraint, если этого слова нет - то имя назначается БД автоматически. разумеется один ко многим, просто удалите UNIQUE на эти поля. Можете конечно оставить и попытаться вставить две записи с одинаковым полом и посмотреть на ошибку, что бы точно понять что делает unique